# Prove that the amount {0.1} ∗ of all bit-strings are countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let B be the set of (final) bit strings starting with 1, in addition to the empty string. Show on B is countable. Tip: a bit string can be considered as a representation of a natural number. For example. the bit string 101 represents the number 20 ∗ 1 + 21 ∗ 0 + 22 ∗ 1 = 5. In general: bn ··· b1b0 represents 20 ∗ b0 +21 ∗ b1 + ··· + 2n ∗ bn.

And heres where I'm really struggeling. How do I prove that the amount {0.1} ∗ of all bit-strings are countable?

Comment: Please, split the two questions into two different posts: they are totally unrelated.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks

Comment: You have just asked two questions in the last five minutes neither of which shows any work of your own. This is not a "do it for me" site.

Comment: Have you understood the hint?  It is quite direct.  In your examples you are missing the superscripts and subscripts.

Comment: What is a *final* bits string ?

Comment: The *amount* of strings is not a countable thing. The string are. And the pattern $\{0|1\}^*$ does not represent the set of strings to be enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

By the given tip, every integer corresponds to a unique string and every string corresponds to a unique integer (if two strings differ in some bits, the integers differ in a sum/difference of distinct powers of $2$, which cannot be zero).

This proves countability.